# Getting started golfing

Tags: support

I'm new to this whole thing, and would like some pointers to getting started

The golfing type languages I'm familiar with are

- APL
- Brainfuck (Check out some of the stuff I've done [here](https://github.com/MicroTransactionsMatterToo/brainfuck-scripts)
- Befunge

And thats about it

Comment: Do you want to specifically learn some golfing language, or are you generally interested in code golf? It's much easier to get into golfing with a popular language you already know, like Python or Javascript. (And BTW, welcome to the site!)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I'm generally interested. I'm highly competent in Python, but I'd like the challenge of using a golfing language. I love APL for how concise it is, and that almost any problem can be solved in one line. Brainfuck I find entertaining. [This](https://github.com/MicroTransactionsMatterToo/brainfuck-scripts/blob/master/strlen.b) is a script I wrote to print the length of a string given to it

Comment: Take a look at the tips for going in [APL](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl), [brainfuck](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12973/tips-for-golfing-in-brainfuck), and [befunge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16090/tips-for-golfing-in-befunge-98).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to be involved:

1. **Take a look at other people's answers.**  Try to figure out what the heck their code does, and if they are doing something clever, upvote it.  This way, you start to grasp the areas different languages excel in.
2. **Write submissions!**  You'll likely get comments helping you golf your submission further, improving your skills.
3. If you want, **write your own golfing language**!  If you've found an interesting niche, or you think you can outperform a different language, then make one!  Or, if you want, you could add to the *many* esoteric languages this community has written.
4. **Write some challenges.**  Make sure to post it in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), but writing challenges is my personal favorite part of this site.

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot